# re-combine shower and tub in master bath

Tags: shower, bathtub, renovation, diy-vs-pro

I have separate tub and shower, and the shower plumbing is in the wall that separates the two, and the tub faucet is on the deck (?) of the fiberglass tub. 
[image: Master Bath: shower wall]
I am considering doing away with the tub altogether and turning that space into a walk-in shower (or doing a combo shower/tub, undecided). I can't find any information anywhere on how to turn the shower faucet and handle to the other side (it would be a 180-degree turn as seen from above) or whether that can be done. The wall it is on is about 4.5" wide

I'd really like to keep all the walls and plumbing in place, the size of the tub area is perfect, and the idea is to turn the current shower stall into a built-in linen cupboard or another vanity nook (basic kitchen base and wall cabinets). I'm also not planning to do anything with the double sink vanity that sits across from the tub (updates at a later time).

[image: Master Bath: tub wall]
To add further explanation of the room, the wall at the other end of the tub is actually an exterior wall, unfortunately. Otherwise, a corner tub would fit perfectly there! Alas, this weird house has a notch in the exterior instead of an easy single corner.

This is supposed to be a diy project. My husband and I just got married, just bought the house, just started brand new jobs, and thankfully don't have to worry about kids just yet. So our savings for stuff like this is quite small, but so is our time (both work 40-60 hours/week). He works with electricity/lighting and I'm in engineering, so our theoretical knowledge is excellent, but actual experience is nil. :)

If anyone has any advice or links that could help, I'd really appreciate it!

TLDR: separate tub and shower in master bath. We want to tear out the tub and create a tiled shower in its place, without moving the plumbing.

Comment: DIY??? I’m sure this project won’t ruin these newlyweds marriage. Colleen, there are a lot of pieces to this project, first of which is determining if that’s asbestos wallboard, plaster, etc.  I’d find a patient contractor and explain your budget/timeline to him then listen to what he says. (You’ve started with the most difficult and expensive room in the house, next to the kitchen.)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, everything depends on  how that wet wall between the shower and bath is organized, and nobody knows that yet. In any case, you won't be "turning" the shower faucet and handle; you'll almost certainly be installing a new one, probably on some new piping.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, that is exactly what my plan is, probably cut out the old hot & cold supplies pretty low and use PEX and Sharkbites to bring them back up to a new valve/mixer/faucet etc. I'm sorry if my use of "turn" was confusing, I had trouble trying to describe exactly what the end goal is with the shower head.

I've already removed the shower faucet handle to try to find the problem with the current one (the only way to get hot water in the shower is to run the tub at the same time), and I'm 90% sure there is nothing else going on inside that wall.

Comment: Lee, there's no asbestos, this house was built in the mid-1980s (and I know how to demo a house down to studs, been there and done it). Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, but this question is much too broad for our Q&A format. There's a world of information on remodeling out there. I suggest you find a good website or book and do some reading. Absolutely come back when you have specific questions about some portion of the project.

Comment: I will offer this bit o' experience, though... live in the place for a while before tearing it up. It's easy to fall into thinking that you don't like some aspect of a home before you really know. When I was younger I did some things out of misplaced enthusiasm that I regretted later. Give it a year.

Comment: @isherwood 100% agree. Tubs can be heaven on a cold winter day. But you never know until you try. Shower-->closet space, tub --> combined, glassed shower and tub? Lots of plumbing to be redone. I'd *not* pick this as a first project. Where is your shop? Even the carpentry is going to be tough. plus cement board and tiling. You've a world of details to consider, and a half finished bath gets annoying after a month or two. You have another?

Comment: If your marriage can survive this project....I think you'll be good for the long run!

Answer (score 0):

You can run your water to the other side through a sleeve pipe to the other side because if you're making a shower you are going to have to build a shower pan with drain, at that time you can run new lines under the new built-up shower pan.

You can also put it in the wall where the other shower is going to be removed and that is where the drain for the shower is already.and if your going to make it a Tub shower with an insert Tub the water can run on the side of the tub wall to the other side.